# AWS console to github

Tags: amazon-web-services, github

I'd like to know if I can use my git repository for AWS console ? In fact i made a rails project on AWS console but I did not find as to how to transfer it on to my Github repository

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Cloud and Github through

- Custom Webhooks: Where you have your code store in github and serve through AWS services like EC2, Lambda, etc.
- AWS Code Pipeline with Code Commit: The AWS code commit service can be configure to listen to github webhook requests, from there you can trigger events when the webhook is received e.g. Build, tests, deploy

[Reference:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-GitHub.html)